# hide a column in vue database using checkbox

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, datatable, multiple-columns, show-hide

I made some code that hides a column by clicking on a checkbox and saves the changes to localstorage. The data is coming from a database so I have only 1 row line. My issue is when I refresh the page the header info is hiding itself which is good, but the rest of the lines are coming back. I would like to hide all of the column not just the header.

[image]

You can see on the image only the headers are not there after refreshing the page.

```js
    mounted() {
                // "data-control-column" is a custom data attribute added to the html checkboxes
    // when a check box changes loop through all, for any that are unchecked, add that checkbox's "data-control-column" value to our array
    $('.opt').change(function(){ 
        var states = [];
        $('.opt').each(function(){
               if(!$(this).is(':checked')) states.push($(this).data('control-column'));         
        });
        setSates(states);
    });
    
    // when we need to set the sate of the UI, loop through the checkboxes checking if their "data-control-column" are in the "states" array 
    // if so, hide the specified column and uncheck the box
    function setSates(states){
         if(states){
             if(!$.isArray( states )) states = JSON.parse(states); // if sates came from localstorage it will be a string, convert it to an array
             $('.opt').each(function(i,e){ 
                 var column =$(this).data('control-column');
                 if($.inArray( column, states ) == -1){
                     $(this).attr('checked', true);
                     $('#myTable td:nth-child('+column+'), #myTable th:nth-child('+column+')').show(); 
                 }
                 else{
                     $(this).attr('checked', false);
                     $('#myTable td:nth-child('+column+'), #myTable th:nth-child('+column+')').hide(); 
                 }
             });
             localStorage.setItem('states', JSON.stringify(states));
         }
    }
    // this will read and set the initial states when the page loads
    setSates( localStorage.getItem('states') );
    
    
           
            },
```

My database:

```js
    data() {
           
    
         return {
                    hidePreLoader: true,
                    price: '',
                    purchase_price: '',
                    selling_price: '',
                    products: {},
                    tableOptions: {
                        tableName: 'products',
                        columns: [
                            {
                                title: 'lang.item_image',
                                key: 'image',
                                type: 'images',
                                source: '/uploads/products',
                                imagefield: 'imageURL',
                                sortable: false,
                            },
                            {title: 'lang.attribute_values', key: 'attribute_values', type: 'text', sortable: true},
                            {title: 'lang.quantity', key: 'test', type: 'text', sortable: true},
                            {title: 'lang.barcode', key: 'bar_code', type: 'text', sortable: true},
                            {title: 'lang.sku_2', key: 'sku_2', type: 'text', sortable: true},
                            {title: 'lang.sku_3', key: 'sku_3', type: 'text', sortable: true},
                            {title: 'lang.sku_4', key: 'sku_4', type: 'text', sortable: true},
                            {title: 'lang.selling_price', key: 'selling_price', type: 'text', sortable: true},
                            {title: 'lang.receiving_price', key: 'purchase_price', type: 'text', sortable: true},
                        ],
                        formatting : ['selling_price','purchase_price'],
                        source: '/products/variantDetails/' + this.id,
                    },
                }
            },
```

and the checkbox:

```html
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-control-column="1" class="opt" />{{ trans('lang.item_image') }}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to mix jQuery and Vue to manage DOM. You can use Vue to shoe/hide any elements you want

Comment: And can you tell me please how can i do that. In vue i do not know how to save changes to localstorage. I am new with vue. Thank you.

Comment: just use `v-if` or `v-show` directive on elements use need to show/hide. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html for instance how to do it. And of course you need to define and change some variables in `data` section in order to manage element's visibility

Comment: Thank you. But still not clear how it will save the option to localstorage after i refreshed the page.

Comment: You need to catch checkbox state changes and modify saved columns state accordingly and save it to local storage as well. And on loading page just use saved columns state from local sotrage